# Convert Option<Result<T, E>> to Option<T>

Tags: rust

Is there a simple way to convert an `Option<Result<T, E>>` to an `Option<T>`, returning `Err` in case of error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`transpose`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.transpose), which does exactly that.

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), String> {
    let _foo: Option<usize> = Some(Err("Foo".to_string())).transpose()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b1c9f389324b702ceee9a99f36a53fbc)

Notice that it transformst the `Option<Result<T, E>>` to `Result<Option<T>, E>`. You would just need to use the `?` or `unrwrap/except` methods to take the `Option<T>` if is not an `E`.

Comment: You can also [just do the match directly](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b1c9f389324b702ceee9a99f36a53fbc) if you don't want to deal with a `Result`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your function does return something like `Return<_>` (so that you can actually `return` an `Err`), an easy way would be: `let b = a.transpose()?;` where `a: Option<Result<T, E>>` and `b: Option<T>`.

Comment: you cannot use `?` inside map iirc

Comment: indeed, edited accordingly.